# Visual Basic .substring error

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB and I was having some issues with the following code.

```
    Dim random As String = "asfdgasfdgasfdgasfd11"
    Dim length As Integer = Nothing

    length = random.Length
    Console.WriteLine(random.Length)
    Console.WriteLine(length)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ReadLine()

    If length <= 20 Then
        Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(0, length))
    ElseIf length <= 40 Then
        Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(0, 20))
        Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(20, length))
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Error:

> " An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index and Length must refer to a location
>   within the string "

I think the error is occurring due to (`20`, `length`)). I tried to assign length to a variable so the program does not crash unless the trying is a specific number of characters.

I am attempting to have a variable of any given length and if it is greater than 20 characters then only print 20 characters per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additional information: Index and Length must refer to a location
>   within the string

That's the point. In your second WriteLine you ask to print the `random` string starting from the 20th character (starting index ok, there are 21 characters) but then it ask to print for 21 chars (length = 21).
Yes, startindex + length = 41 and it is out of the string limits

you could try to fix that line with

```
Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(20, length - 20))
```

or introduce a while loop that prints 20 characters at time

```
length = random.Length
Console.WriteLine(random.Length)
Console.WriteLine(length)
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine()
Console.ReadLine()

Dim curStart = 0 
Dim loopCounter = 0
while(curStart < random.Length)
    Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(curStart, System.Math.Min(20, length - 20 * loopCounter)))
    curStart = curStart + 20
    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1
End While
```

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks for showing me the while loop, that actually solves all my problems with minimal code. 

I was able to fix my initial error with..

Console.WriteLine(random.Substring(20, length - 20))

Thanks for your help!

B